# HtmlRendererCore.PdfSharpCore Version 1.0.1 "No appropriate font found."

Tags: .net-core, html-to-pdf

Getting exception: `No appropriate font found.` while converting HTML to PDF using HtmlRendererCore.PdfSharpCore (Version 1.0.1) package,

at this line:

`var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(HTML, PageSize.A4,0);`

[image]

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I have tried this: to no avail:
https://libraries.io/nuget/PdfSharpCore

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(content, PageSize.A4, (int)PdfPageMode.UseOutlines);`